# Re-setting the colour of buttons on a web page

Tags: javascript, css, button

I have a number of buttons that once clicked change colour from green to red to show they have been clicked.

I would like to create a button that once clicked resets all of the buttons to their original colour (green).

I have tried but the closest solution I have found is by creating a button that resets the entire page but this is not ideal.

Here is the code for my buttons and the function to change its colour:

```
<button id="button1" onclick="myFunction3(); setColor2('button1');">example</button>

<script>
    function setColor2(btn,color) {
        var property=document.getElementById(btn);

        if (window.getComputedStyle(property).backgroundColor == 'rgb()') {
            property.style.backgroundColor=color;
        }
        else {
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#f47121";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can **Remove** all the inline styles like this:

```js
function setColor2(btn, color) {
  var property = document.getElementById(btn);

  if (window.getComputedStyle(property).backgroundColor == 'rgb()') {
    property.style.backgroundColor = color;
  } else {
    property.style.backgroundColor = "#f47121";
  }
}

function reset() {
  var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var button = buttons[i];
    button.removeAttribute("style");
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="button1" onclick="setColor2('button1');">example</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="setColor2('button2');">example</button>
<br><br>
<button id="reset" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
```

> But as suggested before it's better if you can toggle between classnames

Answer (score 0):

This is far easier if you do it all through CSS classes or other attribute selectors rather than directly setting the style like this.

For example, let's go with two CSS rules:

```
button{
  background-color: '#33cc33'; // a mid green
}

button.selected {
  background-color: '#cc3333'; // a red
}
```

Then your code on click can just add the css class of 'selected' to the button in question and your reset function just becomes:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for(var button in buttons){
  button.className = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to grab them by classname and loop through, testing each button. It would be better and easier to maintain if you just add and remove a class, then define class specs in css.

```js
function myFunction3() {
  // whatever this does   
}

function setColor2() {
  var buttonsToChange = document.getElementsByClassName('change-color');

  for (var i = 0; i < buttonsToChange.length; i++) {
    var button = buttonsToChange[i];
    console.log("Button bg color: ", button.style.backgroundColor);
    if (button.style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(244, 113, 33)') {
      button.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(227, 227, 227)';
    } else {
      button.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(244, 113, 33)';
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<button id="button1" class="change-color" onclick="myFunction3(); setColor2();">example</button>
<button id="button2" class="change-color" onclick="myFunction3(); setColor2();">example</button>
<button id="button3" onclick="myFunction3();">example</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for a task like this would be to use jQuery over regular JavaScript. With jQuery you can use class selectors to update all the buttons' colors at once.

HTML:

```
<button class="color-button button-green">Color button 1</button>
<button class="color-button button-green">Color button 2</button>
<button id="reset-color">Reset color</button>
```

CSS:

```
.color-button {}

.button-green {
  background-color: green;
}

.button-red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.color-button').click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('button-green').addClass('button-red');
    });

    $('#reset-color').click(function() {
        $('.color-button').removeClass('button-red').addClass('button-green');
    });
});
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mt8f85jj/